# AWS SES Domain Verification

Tags: amazon-ses

I am trying to verify a domain on aws ses, the domain is managed on google domains. It has been two days since adding the text record in google domains, but still not getting verified in aws ses. I am not sure what could be problem. I would really appreciate if anyone could help.

Comment: What have you done? What has happened?

Comment: I have created AWS SES and my domain point with google so when I trying to update aws ses txt and mx record not able to create or it is not working also, if I using same things with cloudflare or route 53 it was working fine.

Comment: Please add the relevant details (specifics are important!) to the question and it may be possible to answer.

Comment: Means I want to use AWS ses with gcp dns is it possible

Comment: Please help me for the resolution

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: just want to use AWS SES feature, and my domain already pointed with gcp cloud dns, so how to use AWS SES  TXT and MX record with gcp cloud dns.